# type casting when objects are of interface references in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting

I am familiar with `type casting` in `inheritance model`.

Let `SuperClass and SubClass` be parent and child classes;

`SuperClass superClass = new SubClass()`; -- Here the `object` instantiated is a `subclass object`;
but its `reference type` is `SuperClass`; that is only those `methods` of `SuperClass` can be called on the `subclass object`; Any `methods` that are not `inherited/overridden` in `subclass` cannot be called (that is any unique `methods` of `subclass`).

I observed same behavior as above if `SuperClass is an interface` and `SubClass implements it`. That is only those methods declared in `SuperClass interface` are available to be called on the `SubClass` object. Is my understanding correct? But with some `casting`, I can call `methods` that is not part of the interface, which I have observed in my sample code below;

I have made some comments on my understanding as how it works;
but I would like to know if that make sense or if my interpretation is wrong;

```
class Animals {

     public void bark(){
         System.out.println("animal is barking");
     }

}

 interface catIF {
     public void catting();

 }

interface dogIF {
    public void dogging();
 }

class Dog extends Animals implements dogIF {

    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("dog is barking");
    }


    public void dogging() {
        System.out.println("dogging");

    }

}

class Cat extends Animals implements catIF {

    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("cat is barking");
    }


    public void catting() {
        System.out.println("catting");

    }

}

public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        dogIF dog = new Dog();
        //dog.bark(); this fails
        //This method actually actually exists;
        //but it is not available or hidden because dogIF reference
        //limits its availability; (this is similar to inheritance)

        Dog dog2 = new Dog();
        dog2.bark();
        ////prints dog is barking

        Animals an =(Animals) dog;
        an.bark();
        //prints dog is barking
        //by casting we mean, treat the dog as an animals reference
        //but the object itself is a dog.
        //call the bark() method of dog
        //but dog did not have this method in the beginning (see first line
        // in main - when instantiated with interface type)
        }
     }
```

Comment: `dogIF#bark()` does not exist, so you are right about that. Method invocations are resolved, at compile time, based on the declared type of the reference.

Comment: Yes your understand is perfectly fine.

Comment: Inheritance if interfaces is a little flaky in Java -- I'm not sure anyone really understands it.  (I understood it long enough to implement `checkcast`, but the rules are so arcane I've long since forgotten them.)

Comment: But one thing to understand is that when you do an explicit cast (`(Animals)`, eg) then the compiler takes your word for it that the object in question is the type specified.  Under the covers a `checkcast` bytecode assures that what you say is true, but the compiler has no idea whether the `checkcast` will succeed or fail.

Comment: some kind of explicit cast compiler catches it. but some throws classcastException in run-time...I guess the reason those explicit cast are caught in compile time is because those casts can never happen. something like `Cat cat = (Dog) dog`; in the above example; Although both extends from `Animals`

Comment: Casts check whether the object implements the new type before they take effect, and throw a `ClassCastException` if it doesn't. So, either `Cat` or `Dog` extends/implements `Animals` and can be cast to `Animals`, but they don't have a super/subclass relationship to each other so you can't cast one to the other. Although you *could* have an object which extended `Cat` and implemented `dogIF`, if you wanted to describe a cat that shared the latter behavior with dogs... like mine, which will sometimes retrieve a ball.

Comment: @user1988876 - Explicit casts are not "caught" at compile time.  What's diagnosed at compile time is an incompatible assignment.  `Cat cat = (Dog) dog` is no more invalid, to the compiler, than Cat cat = (Dog) anotherCat`.  What the compiler diagnoses is the attempt to assign something declared (by the cast) to be Dog to a Cat variable.  (The compiler would be perfectly happy with `Cat cat = (Cat) dog`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance of interfaces really isn't "flaky" or complicated. They behave exactly the way abstract classes do, with the exceptions that you reference them differently (implements rather than extends) and that you're allowed to inherit as many interfaces as you like but can only have one superclass (abstract or not).

As with other inheritance: If all you know about an object is that it implements an interface, then you can only access it through that interface. If you know that it implements another interface, or a specific superclass, or is an instance of a particular class, then you can cast it to those and access it through the exposed members of those.

So, yes: If all your program knows is that the object is an instance of `Animals`, then all you can do is call what's declared on Animals. That means `bark()` plus whatever methods it inherits from `Object` (since everything is an `Object` directly or indirectly even if that isn't explicitly stated).

If your program knows that the object is an implementation of `dogIF` or `catIF` -- because the variable type says it is, or because you've successfully typecast it to one of those interfaces -- you can also call the method(s) declared by those interfaces.  By the way, the usual convention for interfaces is to name them like classes, with UppercasedFirstLetter... since in many cases the difference between an interface and a class really isn't significant to the folks using it.

If your program happens to know that the object is a `Dog`, you can call anything it inherits from either `Animals` or `dogIF`, or that is provided directly by `Dog`. Of course it could actually be a `Chihuahua` (subclass of dog), but that's OK, the subclass will respond to anything the superclass would have responded to, in "the right way to maintain the semantics". (That is, a `Chihuahua` may respond to `bark()` by saying "yip yip yip grr yip!", but that method really shouldn't cause it to try to bite your ankle.)

Hope that helps. It really isn't that complicated.

Comment: is variable type same as reference type? and regarding your sentence `If your program happens to know that the object is a Dog, you can call anything it inherits from either Animals or dogIF, or that is provided directly by Dog` -- possible only when I declare `Dog dog = new Dog(); but not Animals dog = new Dog() or dogIF dog = new Dog()`

Comment: 1) All object variables in Java are references, so yes. (As opposed to the object's actual type.) (2) If you know the object is a `Dog` -- either because you created it, or because you know that from other context, or because you've just used the `instanceof` operation to check this -- you can safely typecast it to `Dog` and treat it as such. I admit I shorthanded that a bit.

Comment: consider this: `dogIF dog = new Dog()`; The object is a `Dog object`; but this is not allowed: `(Dog)dog.bark()`. I guess I have some misunderstanding here..

Comment: There's no guarantee that an arbitrary `dogIF` can be cast to `Dog` -- but that just means that the cast will throw ClassCastException if the object isn't an instance of what it's being cast to. If it *is* an instance of `Dog`, there's nothing wrong with the typecast... though you may need to be careful to make sure that you're casting the object rather than the result. Try `((Dog)dog).bark()`.

Comment: yes that worked. on a different note, why (Dog)dog.bark() did not work; the precedence goes from left to right, so I cast dog to be Dog and then call bark..?

Comment: Check the Java expression grammar. In most languages, casts are one of the lowest-precedence operators. In specific, in most C-like languages, suffix operators (such as the method call) take precedence over prefix operators. When in any doubt, use parens or break it up into separate calculations to make it explicit.

Comment: You didn't have to write the code behind `checkcast` ... and get it to pass the Sun acceptance test.  There are several non-obvious twists and turns.

Comment: Doesn't entirely surprise me, @HotLicks.

Comment: @keshlam - They actually changed the fine details several times, as they worked on the `invokeinterface` internal implementation (which is a bit messy and slow).  One could kind of figure out how their implementation was changing, from the changes in the spec.