# Performance difference between passing interface and class reloaded

Tags: java, performance, interface, abstract-class

There's a [consensus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571479/the-difference-between-passing-interface-reference-and-class-reference-in-java/21571516#comment32626699_21571516) that using interfaces is better than using classes. I surely agree: a library method accepting `ArrayList` instead of `List` would be a crap.

There's also a consensus that the performance is always the same. Here my [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/InterfaceBenchmark.java) begs to differ.
[image: results]
There are 1 to 4 implementations of both an interface and an abstract class. When more than two implementations get used, the performance starts to diverge. I'm looking for an explanation for this behavior (and also for the origin of the false consensus).

Comment: I disagree with both those "consensuses". I'm not surprised by your benchmark results either.

Comment: @Boann: What's wrong with the first one? Could you elaborate (maybe in an answer)?

Comment: I was being lazy and thought someone would get in with an answer faster but okay I'll give it a go.

Comment: javap -c shows both use JVM instruction invokeinterface. So maybe the hotspot compiler might have nore work on interfaces than classes, there being several interfaces per class. Irreal.

Comment: This article explains it nicely: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue158.html You also have to consider how many implementations of this interface exist (and are actively used) *during* the test - it's really difficult to pull out the right information from such a benchmark! But my own experiments basically confirmed that: When there are more implementations of an interface, calling the respective methods becomes noticably slower.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> There's a consensus that using interfaces is better than using classes.

This is overly simplistic. Both interfaces and abstract classes have advantages over each other.

The answer you link to suggests declaring variables as java.util.List, rather than java.util.ArrayList where possible. It's correct that using List gives you more flexibility to choose a different implementation class later, and thus is a good thing to do when you don't need ArrayList-specific methods (e.g., `.trimToCapacity()`). However, this advice has *nothing to do with interfaces or classes in general*, and would be just as true if java.util.List were an abstract class.

> There's also a consensus that the performance is always the same.

The popular advice is that one should not worry about performance differences between classes and interfaces, and should choose between them based on good programming principles instead. This is good advice to prevent programmers fretting about unimportant performance differences; however it is sometimes misunderstood to imply that there is *no* difference, which is not true. There **is** a small difference: classes are faster.

With the method call through a class, there is a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) at a fixed offset in the class, and the pointer to the desired method implementation is found at a known offset within that table, so the jump to the target is quite simple. However, while a class can extend only one superclass, a class can implement any number of interfaces, so method calls through an interface are more complicated. For interface calls, it has to look up the class's list of interfaces first to find the interface that's wanted, before it can look up the method implementation in that interface's table.

> When more than two implementations get used, the performance starts to diverge.

Whether classes or interfaces are used, the polymorphic call causes a pipeline flush on the CPU, because the CPU can't see the target of the jump in advance, and this has a high cost. When the call site is known at run time to be oligomorphic (*oligo* meaning 'few'), performance increases sharply because a good JVM handles these cases specially. For the monomorphic case the JVM can jump directly to the single target method, or even inline it. For the dimorphic case it implements `o.f();` as if by (not valid syntax): `if (o.getClass() == A.class) A::f(o) else B::f(o);`.

Actually I'm not sure why the dimorphic case seems to be as fast in your benchmark as the monomorphic case – shouldn't the CPU's branch predictor get it wrong half the time on random data? Perhaps there's other subtleties at work there...

See also:

- https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/VirtualCalls
- https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/InterfaceCalls

Comment: I guess there's CMOVcc instead of branching in the bimorphic case. Given that case 0 has a rather high latency (mul+add, i.e., 4 cycles), it leaves enough time to compute case 1. Then only a single cycle for CMOVcc gets added. But I haven't looked at the asm yet.

Comment: @maaartinus Perhaps it's simply that case 1 is faster than case 0 because it doesn't have a multiplication, so the average case is faster if you're doing a mix of case 0 and case 1.

Comment: This would be possible, too, but then there'd be the branch penalty half of the time, which I guess would weight more.