# Performance overhead of a Java interface over abstract class

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

In my testing, calling a function on a defined interface in Java takes about 200 nanos longer to execute than using an extended abstract class (on my macbook).  Is that expected overhead?

Comment: can you post your benchmarking code

Comment: I suspect that you are not benchmarking in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that your benchmark is broken (as Java benchmarking is [pretty hard](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks)). The overhead must be much lower than 200 ns, unless you're running some historical CPU.

Nonetheless, interfaces are sometimes slightly slower, but things are much more complicated as you can see in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608240/performance-difference-between-passing-interface-and-class-reloaded).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the specifics of the Java implementation.  However, based on my experience working with a compiler for a different language, I think that since a class can extend only one abstract class but can implement multiple interfaces, the process of searching for the right method may take slightly longer since there's some additional complexity in the data structures needed to support dynamic dispatch.  So this result doesn't surprise me.