# Java Junit precise Benchmarking and conclusion of complexity

Tags: java, performance, junit, big-o, benchmarking

I am using java and I have used junit-benchmarks-0.7.2 for JUNIT performance tests , it works fine for the part of warm ups , multiple runs for test functions and for plotting results , i just want to ask about two features that i can't find in junit-benchmark : 
1-it is not precise for execution time in milliseconds (specially in plots , so i just have plots for functions taking more than 0.1 sec in execution

2-Is there a plugin that can give rough or exact estimation for the complexity of my code ??
even if it displays the performance of my code vs the expected performance for cases like O(N^2) or O(N) or how ever it calculates it ??? (it doesn't matter if it is free or paid plugin , I just want one to do the task )

Comment: 1) Rewrite the test to run longer. Even when using the nanoTime() call, a longer run will produce better accuracy. 2) Can't help; I've never heard of one. 3) Benchmarking Java on more than a single-function basis can be incredibly frustrating. In large programs I've seen 20% run-to-run performance variation despite allowing full JIT warmup and hotspot stabilization and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [this is so far the answer](http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/JUNITBENCH-21):

> Won't fix; will stick with millis as the default granularity. If somebody really needs nanosecond-grade timing, run your benchmarks with caliper.

This is what I'd actually recommend, too, as to me `junit-benchmarks` doesn't seem to be as advanced. But I may be wrong as I haven't watched it closely.

You can write a JUnit test which is also a caliper benchmark like [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608240/performance-difference-between-passing-interface-and-class-reloaded), if it helps.

Concerning the complexity estimator, there were such plans for caliper, but I strongly doubt that anyone did it. You could do it yourself... in a few hours, I guess. I'm afraid, that it won't be really useful: It can just extrapolate what it sees and there may be problems which manifest themselves only outside of the measured range. So you should better interpolate only and then it loses sense as you can spot problems without the tool.

Comment: so caliper is the answer for question 1 and no answer for question 2

thanks :)